# About how to refer XHMTL file converted PDF file with CPF(Content Processing Framework) from browser

Tags: pdf, xhtml, xquery, marklogic

I'd like to reference XHTML files converted from PDF files using MarkLogic's Content Processing Framework(Pipeline:PDF Conversion(Page Layout)) from the browser.
Although it could be confirmed that the XHTML file can be displayed in the browser via the HTTP server with the following code, the link of css or jpeg file referenced from the XHTML file is not valid and can not be displayed correctly.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

My Code(index.xqy):

```
declare variale $uri := "/aaa/bbb/ccc_pdf.xhmlt";
xdmp;set-response-content-type("text/html;charset=uft-8")
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI "-//W3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 
Strict//EN "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-strict.dtd">,
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.rog/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<iframe src="get-file.xqy?uri={xdmp:uri-encode($uri)}">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code(get-file.xqy):

```
let $uri := xdmp:get-request-field("uri")
let $mimetype := xdmp:uri-content-type($uri)
return
if(fn:doc($uri))
then (
xdmp:set-response-content-type($mimetype),
fn:doc($uri)
)
else ()
```

Comment: I don't know about the format of a xqy file, but the doctype seems to be missing the C in PUBLIC, and "w3.org" is misspelled in the xmlns. Also, is the comma after the doctype OK? And I'm not sure if this is important, but validators will complain that the iframe element doesn't exist in XHTML 1.0 Strict and that the head element is missing.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.
The following are correct:

Comment: The following are correct:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Then, the comma after the DOCTYPE is not a problem because it is the rule when writing HTML with MarkLogic XQuery.

I didn't know that IFRAME elements were deprecated in strict DTDs. Thank you pointed out. I did not notice that the IFRAME element was not particularly error.
However, changing the IFRAME element to the EMBED element does not change the result.

Comment: Can you edit the question and correct the typos?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with xqy at all, so all I could comment on was the issues that I could see. Sorry I haven't been any help.